# Hot to get DOM or jQuery element by mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseclick-event

How to get DOM or jQuery element by mouse click?
For example I have the next code:

```
$("*").mouseup(
 function() 
 {
    var clickedElement = ???????????????
 }
);
```

So, how to init 'clickedElement' variable?
Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Inside an event handler, `this` refers to the DOM element the event was raised on.

```
$("*").mouseup(function() {
    var clickedElement = this;
});
```

To get a jQuery element, just pass `this` to `jQuery`.

**But**: It would be **much much much better** to use **event delegation**, instead of binding an event handler to *every element*. You can get the origin of the event with [**`event.target`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
    var clickedElement = event.target;
});
```

**And a further note:** This will not necessarily give you the clicked element, but the element over which the mouse button was released, which can be different from the element the button was pressed. You might want to bind to the `click` event.

---

I also suggest to [read a jQuery tutorial where these basics are covered](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me:_Using_selectors_and_events).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to attach an event to every DOM element (which I wouldn't recommend)...

```
$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
   var clickedElement = event.target;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Vr2ZN/).

Here, any element's event will bubble up all the way to `document`, where it will be handled, and the originating element that started the event will be in `event.target`.

Answer (score 2):

Use **this**. i.e.:

```
$("*").mouseup(  function()   {     
    var clickedElement = this; //HTML DOM Element
    var $clickedElement = $(this); //jQuery Wrapped HTML DOM Element
} );
```